# How can I use Azure Stream Analytics to use an on-premise SQL Server as an Output?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-stream-analytics

I'm following [the instructions to set up App Insights to spool to SQL using Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-code-sample-export-sql-stream-analytics), but I'm trying to deviate slightly to use an on-premise SQL server (that the web application already uses) over VPN.

At the point of adding the output, this is failing with:

[image: The JSON provided in the request body is invalid. Property 'server' value '' is not acceptable]

Is it the case that IP addresses are not supported, or is it something more fundamental than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for answers directly to your question, which Jean-Sébastien answers succinctly. But an alternative architecture, if you haven't considered it already...

You could stream to a transient Azure SQL Database or Blob storage (likely cheaper depending on your workload), and then use [Azure Data Factory tunnelled via a Self-Hosted Data Factory Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to "send" the data back to on-premise SQL.

Data Factory V2 also has blob triggers, so rather than needing a schedule it could pickup any new blobs in micro batches.

I say "send" in quotation marks as the Integration Runtime actually creates an outgoing connection to from on-premise to Azure, yet gives the capability for push-like data transfer.

If data factory proves useful, here is a guide creating copy pipelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-portal

Albeit this guide is for on-prem sql to blob, but it gives you a stronger starting point.

Comment: I've already got the data going to blob storage so I just need to work out how to get it to stream to my on-premise database, so this at least gives a starting point, even if that guide is a little vague

Comment: Hi @RowlandShaw I've edited my answer to add a guide for copying between data stores. If you haven't used data factory before I'd recommend starting at the overview page, as there are gems in the data factory documentation as you move around it.

Answer (score 2):

At this time only Azure SQL Databases are supported in Azure Stream Analytics.
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Thanks,

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)

Comment: My end goal here is to create a Power BI report that combines Application Insights data with data from an on-premise database, and it seems I'm hitting brick walls at every turn. It's a shame @AzureSupport and the documentation didn't just tell me that when I first started poking them last Thursday :(

Comment: Sorry for this, let me talk to the team to improve the documentation on the ASA side. To connect local sources to PowerBI, did you try the "On Premises Gateway" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem